# I have to write an SQL statement to create a table skill using DDL commands. the field description can be NULL and the default value is NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE skill
(
  id BIGINT(20),
  description VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

The portal says wrong answer. I don't understand what is wrong in this code.
After execution, it says'0 rows affected'.

Comment: 0 rows effected is good, its a table not a data set.

Comment: `0 rows affected` is not a 'wrong answer'.

Answer (score 0):

DDL statements do not affect any records, they affect objects, so a successful execution of a DDL statement is expected to return "0 rows affected".

Your DDL seems correct, although explicitly stating `default null` is a tad overly robust. Many (most?) DBAs I've worked with would omit it and simply use something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE skill
(
  id BIGINT(20),
  description VARCHAR(255),
  name VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Comment: Yeah ..it worked. I didn't know the meaning of diamonds and other symbols in an ER diagram. Got it now, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
CREATE TABLE skill
(
    id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(255),
    name VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE table skill
(
 id           BIGINT(20),
 description  varchar(255) NULL,
 name         varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 primary key(id)
);
```

Please use the above query.